# Google Heatmap - Visualizing data when there is a wide variance in weights assigned

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

We are creating a Google Map with heatmap layer. We are trying to show the energy use of ~1300 companies spreadout over the United States. For each of the companies we have their lat/long and energy use in kWh. Our plan is to weight the companies on the heatmap by their kWh use. We have been able to produce the map with the heatlayer, however, because we have such a huge variance in energy use (ranging from thousands to billions of kWh), the companies using smaller amounts of energy are not showing up at all. Even when you zoom in on their location nothing you can't see any coloring on the map.

Is there a way to have all companies show up in the heatmap, no matter how small their energy use is? We have tried setting the MaxIntensity, but still have some of the smaller companies not showing up. We are also concerned about setting the MaxIntensity too low since we are then treating a companies using 50 million kWh the same as one using 3 billion kWh. Is there anyway to set a MinIntensity? Or to have some coloring visible on the map for all the companies?

Answer (score 3):

Heatmap layers accept a gradient property, expecting an array of colors as its value. These colors **will always have linear mapping against your sample starting from zero**. Also, the first color (let's say, gradient[0]) should be transparent, for it's supposed to map zeroes or nulls. If you give a non transparent color to the first gradient point, then the whole world will have that color.

This means that if, for example, you enter a gradient of 20 points, all points weighting less than 1/20th of the maximum will show as interpolate between gradient[0] (transparent) and gradient[1] (the first non transparent color in your gradient). This will result in semi transparent datapoints for non normalized samples.

If you need to somehow flatten your values universe, you'll have to feed the Heatmap with precomputed values. For example, the value of log(kWh) will be a flatter curve to represent.

Another workaround would be to offset every value with a fraction of the maximum (for example, 10% of the maximum), so the minimum will be displaced from the zero in at least one color interval.